# Difference between (object)null and null

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a piece of code like this

```
object o = (object)null;

object oo = null;
```

what is the difference between them?

Comment: Logically no difference

Comment: Both will make object null

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.

The expression `null` is not tied to any specific type.  It's actual type is inferred through how it's used.

For the statement:

```
object oo = null;
```

You are assigning the `null` expression to a variable of type `object` so it is inferred to be the value `null` of type `object`.

For the statement:

```
object o = (object)null;
```

You are *explicitly* casting the expression `null` to `object` and assigning to a variable of type `object`.  Collectively, `(object)null` has the type object.  The compiler does not infer anything since everything is explicitly known.

In both of these cases, they behave exactly the same because we know what type the expression has to be.  However if we don't know what the type is, it will lead to errors.

e.g., using `var` where the types must be inferred by compiler.

```
var o = null; // error
var oo = (object)null; // ok
```

Comment: the null is not inferred in the first code. it is converted to object implicitly.